# Cleaner way to group dictionary item on 2 levels

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of a grid defined:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, decimal> _details;
```

where the key is **Item1 -> ColumnIndex**, **Item2 -> RowIndex**

I have a complex grouping method that should group 3 dictionary items together,

from the same row and the column is 1,2,3 or 4,5,6 or 7,8,9 or 10,11,12 then process them
I have done it and it works perfectly but I is there a cleaner way to do it?

my code:

private bool IsValid()
{
    // check every value with quantity and value or both null
    // check total not null

```
if (_details.Count() <= 0)
    return false;

var rows = _details.GroupBy(c => c.Key.Item2);
foreach (var item in rows)
{
    foreach (var subItem in item)
    {
        switch (subItem.Key.Item1)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                if (!item.Any(c => c.Key.Item1.In(2, 3)))
                    return false;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                if (!item.Any(c => c.Key.Item1 == 1) || item.Any(c => c.Key.Item1 == 3))
                    return false;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                if (!item.Any(c => c.Key.Item1 == 1) || item.Any(c => c.Key.Item1 == 2))
                    return false;
                break;
            }
                        // code continues the same way up to 12 
        return true;
    }
```

Edit: data

```
_details = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, decimal>();

_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 1), 10);
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(2, 1), 10);
// if abouve data only added return true
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(4, 2), 10);
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(6, 2), 10);
// still true 
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(10, 4), 10);
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(11, 4), 10);
//still true
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(2, 2), 10);
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(8, 1), 10);           
_details.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(10, 3), 10);
// adding the last 3 return false
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have some sample data and desired output?

Comment: @RubensFarias I will Add some.

Comment: What happens if all three are set, i.e. Qunt, Cash, and Credit? Should this be a `true` or a `false`? Your code would make it `true`, but is that correct?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh yes it's not correct, I will have to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can somewhat simplify this by interpreting sets of numbers as sets of bits.

Convert a set of small numbers 0..11 to a single `int` such that if a number `k` is present in the set, then bit number `k` is set in the `int`; otherwise, the corresponding bit is zero.

For example, your illustration would be converted to a number `010 001 101 011` in binary (spaces are for separating the groups). Note that the bits are reversed, because cell #1 is on the left, while bit number zero is on the right. This corresponds to octal number `2153` (octal is convenient when you consider triples of bits).

Given a mask like that, you can check each triplet of bits for validity. There are only eight possibilities - `000`, `001`, `010`, `011`, `100`, `101`, `110`, and `111`. Of them only `000`, `011`, and `101` are valid.

Here is one way of implementing this:

```
var rows = _details.GroupBy(c => c.Key.Item2);
foreach (var item in rows) {
    // Note the -1: this is because your items are numbered 1..12,
    // while bits are numbered 0..11
    int mask = item.Aggregate(0, (p, v) => p | (1 << (v.Key.Item1-1)));
    for (i = 0 ; i != 4 ; i++) {
        int bits = (mask >> (3*i)) & 7; // Shift, and take the las three bits
        if (bits != 0 && bits != 3 && bits != 5) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```